# Почему не срабатывает форма в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

*Названия изменил для примера*

Код модели: `/models/myModel.php`

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class pressureForm extends Model
{
    public $date;
    public $pressure;
    public $condition;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['date', 'pressure', 'condition'], 'required']
        ];
    }
}
```

Код контроллера `controllers/SiteController.php`

```
public function actionPage()
{

    $pressureForm = new form();

    return $this->render('page',[
        'pressureForm' => $pressureForm,
    ]);
}
```

Код `views/page.php`

```
/* @var $this yii\web\View */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;

?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

        <?= $form->field($pressureForm, 'date')->widget(yii\jui\DatePicker::className(), ['dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM-dd']) ?>

        <?= $form->field($pressureForm, 'pressure')->textInput(array('value'=>$pressure)); ?>

        <?= $form->field($pressureForm, 'condition')->radioList(['1' => "Да", '0' => 'Нет']); ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('', ['class' => 'btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus']) ?>
    </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

И тут я получаю ошибку

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException
>   Getting unknown property: app\models\form::condition
>   in vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php at line 143

```
        foreach ($this->_behaviors as $behavior) {
            if ($behavior->canGetProperty($name)) {
                return $behavior->$name;
            }
        }
    }
    if (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
        throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    } else {
        throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
    }
}
```

Когда удаляю из формы строку с `condition`, то всё работает, а так же когда меняю `radioList` на `textInput`, то страница тоже срабатывает, почему так?

Comment: поле `condition` есть в базе?

Comment: Нету, а должно быть?

Comment: Добавил в базу значение condition, то же самое

Comment: Может я чего-то не понимаю, но у вас в модели    `pressureForm`, а в контролере   `new form`. Почему не `new pressure` ?

Comment: `/models/myModel.php` -> `class pressureForm extends Model` ? И почему в исключении `app\models\form`?

Comment: Спасибо, нужно писать было new pressure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно писать было `new pressureForm` вместо `new form`

Comment: по ходу все же new pressureForm